It is not possible to deploy a project as a web application or a library, as well as to delete a bound library
I create scripts using Tanaike library, but after creation I can't deploy the created project as a web application or library, as well as delete the added library.
When I start to deploy the project the download just hangs and can last for several hours (haven't checked anymore), restarting the script doesn't help, tried copying the project, also doesn't help.
When I try to delete an added library, nothing happens.
What can be the problem?

Server error? Try later or in a new script project.

Have you tried some basic troubleshooting on other browsers, such as Firefox, Opera, (if you're using a Mac, Safari), to see if the same issue is occurring?

@SputnikDrunk2 I've tried different browsers, it didn't work.

@TheMaster There are no problems with regular projects, it is the projects created or updated via App script Api that are not deployed

Can you provide your request body for correctly replicating your current issue?

@Tanaike I'm trying to deploy as a web App or Library from project menu

Thank you for replying. From @Tanaike I'm trying to deploy as a web App or Library from project menu, when I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to try to think of a solution. If you give me time to do it, I'm glad. But, if you are required to want an answer soon, please tell me.

@Tanaike My question doesn't need a quick fix, I can wait, thank you for your help
